# My File Browser App Doesn't show any files, other than LOST.DIR

Tags: android, file, browser, sd-card

I have made an app in Android, which is basically a File Browser. It shows all the files correctly in all devices perfectly, but not in one of my phones - Xperia SL.

It used to work properly in that phone, before I used ASYNC Task to load files asynchronously. After I did that, id doesn't show any file or any folder, just the LOST.DIR folder.

It works in all other phones perfectly, I have tested in 4-5 devices.

Can any one please suggest something?

Comment: What absolute path is it scanning?  What do *other* file browser apps show on that device?  Do you get any exceptions, perhaps hidden by non-logging catch blocks?

Comment: Other file browser apps are perfectly working. I am scanning from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). This app works perfectly on all other devices, this is what bugs me.

Comment: What is the **actual path** returned by that?  What is the actual path scanned by the other apps?  Also, you'll need to post a minimal version of your code (which generates this unexpected result) if you want meaningful help.

Comment: `SYNC Task to load files asynchronously.` ?? Can you explain what you are doing? Loading files? You only have to display some file names.

Comment: Thank you all for the response on my problem. I have fixed the problem from a previous backup I had. The main problem was because I was trying to create a folder in my sdcard0/ directory using mkdir(), just removed all of them and its fine now.